# How to stop my Python IDLE from restarting every time I import numpy module?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pycharm, python-idle

I imported numpy module in my script but whenever I execute it in my IDLE it is getting restarted every time saying:

> ========== RESTART: C:\Users\2303p\Desktop\python_code\np_array.py  ==========
>           =============================== RESTART: Shell ===============================

Even tried executing the script file from command prompt but no error there as well it simply doesn't print anything.

Below is the code:

```
import numpy as np

list1 = [1,2,3,4]

print(list1)

array1 = np.array(list1)
```

Just execute above in IDLE using F5 and restart message is displayed and nothing is printed.

Same code when executed in Pycharm prints:

> Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005).

Comment: I am not sure about PyCharm but you can use command line (or terminal depending your OS). 1) Open a command line, 2) Change directory to the file's directory such as `cd C:\Users\2303p\Desktop\python_code`, 3) Run the python file like `python np_array.py`

Comment: Tried it but nothing was printed nor was there any error.

Comment: It appears that the process running np_array.py is crashing.  Possibly, your python and numpy versions are mis-matched.  Shell notices and starts a new remote process.  To debug a bit, start IDLE from Command Prompt with 'python -m idlelib'.  Then try your statements interactively, or comment all by 1 in the editor, and uncomment the next if that works.

Comment: My python version is 3.7.0, numpy version I tried with both 1.7.1  and 1.6.5 same issue with both.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is behavior or python shell every time you run your **script_file.py** (any file name) using F5 it will restart the shell and and load every thing from scratch.

```
1. Load every import statement
2. It will initialize each variable again.
3. Initialize every function again.
```

[image]

**Suggestion** : If you don't want to reload each and every thing again and again you should go for **Anaconda IDE** it will be easy to use.

**EDITED :**
Try to restart (close and reopen) your IDE, Also **print(array1)** at end it seems that you are not printing it.
[image]

Comment: But why after it encounters import statement it again prints restart shell, and my list variable is also not printed ?

Comment: Same code when I run in pycharm it says 'Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)'.

Comment: I have added a new picture please have a look, and try to print your list at end then run.

Comment: By using shift-F5 instead of F5, one can now run code from the editor *without* restarting from scratch.  This is in 3.8.0b4 and 3.7.4.  But psingh issue is the shell restarting itself.

Comment: I don't think it has got to do anything with print statement.

Comment: I tried to replicate this issue, If we are not printing np_list at end then nothing is getting printed as output.